# How to stop video player on samsung Smart TV App without to show the black screen

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, video-player, smart-tv

Hi I'm developing Samsung app with SDK and emulator 4.5. I have a issue..The App shows by videoPlayer some videos loaded on server. My issue is: when the video play and I push button STOP, the video stops and the screen becomes black..I'd like to show the screen with the first frame of the video.
I have tried to do:

```
sf.service.VideoPlayer.setKeyHandler(tvKey.KEY_STOP, function()
{
        if(Popup.getPopup()==Popup.getNPOPUP() && Similars.getOpenS()==false){
            //videoPlayer.enterVideo(videoPlayer.url,videoPlayer.title,videoPlayer.from,videoPlayer.axoid,videoPlayer.nid); //riparte l'esecuzione del video
            sf.service.VideoPlayer.stop();

                            videoPlayer.play();//insert function play 
            sf.service.VideoPlayer.pause();// stop video

            videoPlayer.setFullScreen();
            sf.service.VideoPlayer.show();

            sf.service.VideoPlayer.pause();//stefa

        }
});
```

I have inserted:

```
videoPlayer.play();//insert function play 
sf.service.VideoPlayer.pause();// stop video
```

The play works but the pausa command not work
How can I do? Have you got a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of stop, you can rewind video at start, and then pause it.

Comment: How can I do to know the time video is played?

Comment: looks like sf.service.VideoPlayer have limited API, you can try to use more low-level approach: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00055/index.html

Comment: I havent't found any solution in the link. With remote control I push button sequence STOP, PLAY and PAUSE and I get it, but it seems not allowed programmatically...

Comment: In the link is tutorial how to make video application, that directly use INFOLINK-PLAYER, it have events and methods for playback control.
If you target 2012+ devices, you can use <video> tag and html5 video api.

Comment: are videoPlayer and sf.service.VideoPlayer referencing to same object?
Pause command is ignored during buffering, you can try call it after several seconds.

Comment: I try and response to you

Comment: I tried setTimeout(function(){},3000); but does't work..

Comment: Then I can`t help you here. Try to implement player, using guide from samsungdforum site. link in earlier comment.

Comment: I resolved with function above

Comment: You can post answer with solution and mark it as accepted. It may help future visitors with similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have inserted below

```
sf.service.VideoPlayer.stop();

setTimeout(function(){sf.service.VideoPlayer.pause();},2000); //delay function called of 2000 millisecond
```

I resolved my issue.
if delay time is not enough, you can increase the time to get the finish request.